# How do I import a column from a table to another table?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have two tables: `customers` and `customer_listing`.

`customer.id` is the same as `customer_listing.id`, they are the same costumer and there is mostly the same data in each table for the same id.

However I need to import two columns, `type` and `events`, from `customer_listing` to `customers` in order to get rid of `customer_listing`.

But I have no idea how to do it nicely and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your type and events columns are `varchar(10)`, just edit to whatever they really are:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD COLUMN type VARCHAR(10), ADD COLUMN events VARCHAR(10);

UPDATE customers c INNER JOIN customer_listing cl ON c.id = cl.id  
SET c.type = cl.type, c.events = cl.events;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, if you want to copy the data from `customer_listing` to `customers` you can do something like:

```
udpate customers c, customer_listing cl set c.type=cl.type, c.events=cl.events where c.id=cl.id;
```